# Does grave sand eating gives sense of calm?

Tags: practical-islam, source-identification

Today I was with my wife at her mother grave, as it’s been less than a week my wife cries a lot but while we were at her mother grave and crying, her neighbor told her to eat the sand/clay from the grave it will give u satisfaction. I was unsure but I am aware there is nothing like that in Quran as it’s bidat. 
Is there any thing such as “eating grave sand to get closure/satisfaction”?

Comment: 1) It's recommended that women don't visit the graveyard. 2) There is no documented proof of such a practice afaik.

Comment: @Ahmed is there any hadith relating to not visiting the graveyard by women?

Answer (score 1):

> Does grave sand eating gives sense of calm?

No. There's no such thing in Islam. Besides, Islam strongly praises hygiene and cleanliness. Grave sand has lots of bacteria and parasite eggs in it. Eating grave sand will hurt your body, and anything that hurts your body is not allowed in Islam and is strongly reproached. Plus, there's no documented proof for such a belief.

Wahhabist scholars do not allow women to visit graveyards. But it is actually considered a bid'at, since Fatima (Salam-o-all alayha) used to go to Hamza's grave on Fridays.*(Mostadrak-A'sahihin; Vol 1, Page 377. Vol 3, Page 28.)*